# Prove that the line $PQ$ passes through a fixed point

Tags: analytic-geometry

A right isosceles triangle $AOB$ ($O$ being the origin), is such that when $AO$ and $BO$ are extended to points $P$ and $Q$ the relation $2AP.BQ=AB^2$ holds. Prove that the line $PQ$ passes through a fixed point. I tried writing some equations of lines and using parametric equation, tried to get a relation in the distances. But, nothing worked out. How to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: AO and BO are extended so that A is between O and P and B between O and Q?

Comment: It has not been stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

For ease of calculations, let's us assume right angle at the vertex $O$ 
Let the vertices $A(a, 0)$ on the x-axis & $B(0, a)$ on the y-axis & similarly. let the points $P(h, 0)$ & $Q(0, k)$  Now, we have $$AP=h-a$$   $$BQ=k-a$$ $$AB=\sqrt{a^2+a^2}=a\sqrt 2$$

Now, applying the condition: $2(AP)(BQ)=(AB)^2$ 
$$2(h-a)(k-a)=(a\sqrt2 )^2$$  $$(h-a)(k-a)=a^2$$ $$a=\frac{hk}{h+k}$$

Now, the equation of the line: PQ $$y-0=\frac{k-0}{0-h}(x-h)$$
$$y=\frac{k}{h}(h-x)$$

Comment: Who said $A$ and $B$ lie on coordinate axis. Also, how does this show that the line passes through a fixed point.